# How to grab an coordinates of an address a user has entered into google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

so in my app the user enters a place like "McDonalds in London" (or an address) and then after google maps finds the specific location, I want to grab those coordinates and use them in my app. Does anyone know how I can do that?!?!
How do I access the google app's coordinates, or if i use fragment activity, how do I enter a search box for them to enter an address and grab those coordinates? I'm not sure which way is easier.

please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
List<Address> foundAddresses = null;
foundAddresses = new Geocoder(this).getFromLocationName("McDonalds in London", 1);
double latitude = foundAddresses.get(0).getLatitude();
double longitude = foundAddresses.get(0).getLongitude();
```

You could have passed in any number in the call to `getFromLocationName()` in the event that you expected more than one match for `"McDonalds in London"`.

Comment: Oh thanks man, that helped! I also found this nefty tutorial online. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49k7qT1cKpU&list=PLVTeA3WccG_6a3NeZYPWpjGgaljA_zqle&index=17